# CSS dropdown: whole ul changes its height

Tags: html, css, dropdown

Good evening,

I created a dropdown-menu like this:

[JSFiddle-Dropdown](https://jsfiddle.net/d0dt9jy9/)

```
<nav class="navigation">
    <ul>
        <li id="welc"><a href='#'>Willkommen</a></li>
        <li id ="proj"><a href='#'>Projekte</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href='#'>Natur</a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>Objekte</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href='#'>Bilderrechte</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>Impressum</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

My **Problem** is the following:

When im hovering "Projekte" the whole *< nav >* changes its height. 
How can I fix this?

Comment: Your <li id ="proj"> should not have a space between the id and = symbol. Should be <li id="proj">. This isn't to fix your issue, just something worth noting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xfs9ungg/)

```
body {
text-align: center;
font-family: 'Lucida Grande', helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 16px;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
}

.navigation{
display: inline-block;
text-align: center;
margin-left: -500px;
margin-top: 20px;
position: fixed;
background: #409ED5;
border-radius: 15px 50px
}

.navigation ul{
margin-top: 4px;
}

.navigation ul ul{
 position: absolute;
 /*width:200px;*/ //optional         
}

.navigation ul li{
width: 120px;
border-left: 5px, solid #666;
float: left;
cursor: pointer;
padding: 10px 15px;
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
border-radius: 15px 50px;
list-style-type: none;    
}

.navigation ul li:hover{
background: #00A2FF;
border-left: 5px solid #18E9FF;
}

.navigation ul li:hover a{
font-weight: bold;
color: #fff;
}

#proj:hover ul{
display: block;
}

#proj ul{
display: none;
}

.navigation ul li a{
font-family: georgia;
font-weight: normal;
font-style: italic;
font-size: 20px;
margin-bottom: 5px;
margin-top: 5px;
line-height: 16px;
text-decoration:none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in your css

```
.navigation
{
    height:43px;max-height:43px; // ADD THIS 
    overflow: hidden; // REMOVE THIS
}
```

Comment: Should also include a height to the <li id="proj"> element

Comment: Thank you, it fixed my issue